# No laser scan received

Tags: ros, navigation, amcl-pose, localilzation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use **amcl** to localize my robot using a bag file. Steps I do are these:

1. Publishing the **map**: `rosrun map_server map_server map.yaml`
2. Running **amcl**: `rosrun amcl amcl scan:=base_scan _odom_frame:=odom_combided`
3. Playing the bag file: `rosbag play small.bag`

Published topics are:

```
/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates
/amcl_pose
/base_odometry/odom
/base_odometry/odometer
/base_odometry/state
/base_scan
/clock
/initialpose
/map
/map_metadata
/move_base_simple/goal
/particlecloud
/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tilt_scan
/torso_lift_imu/data
/torso_lift_imu/is_calibrated
```

But **amcl** node prints out this message continuously: `[ WARN] [1391522838.082207618]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1391522838.082082 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /base_scan topic.`

And **/amcl_pose** publishes nothing.

**rxgraph** output:
[image: rxgraph]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126111/no-laser-scan-received/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-02-06**:
can you post your tf tree?

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2014-06-02**:
It's not just a typo `odom_combided` != `odom_combined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are playing back a bagfile, you should probably use simulated time, since the timestamps on the recorded and played back messages will not match the current system time (the "no laser scan recieved for *huge number* of seconds" is a good indicator of this). To use sim time, you should set the "use_sim_time" parameter to true before starting AMCL:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

And when starting  your bagfile, you should tell it to broadcast the clock (so that the current system time matches the timestamps on  your messages being played):

```
rosbag play small.bag --clock
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on 2014-02-04**:
Now it says:  [ WARN] [1391568852.036509093, 1302532602.518714771]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1391568852.036509093, 1302532602.518714771]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-05**:
Have you given AMCL a starting localization, either via parameter or from RVIZ?

**Comment by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on 2014-02-05**:
@fergs, no should I do it? if yes, how?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-06**:
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack shows how to send an initial pose using RVIZ